# HTML 5 Spell Check On Page Load

Tags: html, spell-checking

Is there a way to make the built in HTML 5 spellcheck test fields on page load?  I want to add this feature to an existing intranet site so that when the user loads a form the spelling errors are displayed.

It seems that the spelling errors are displayed when the user types an invalid value.  I'm trying to show invalid values that were previously saved then served to the page.

Is this possible?
Thanks  ST

Answer (score 0):

```
...
<script>
var e;

function spell()
{
    var sp = document.getElementById('sp');
    var sel = window.getSelection();
    sel.selectAllChildren(sp);
    e = sel.getRangeAt(0);
    select(sp, e.startOffset);
    return true;
}

function select(sp, i)
{
    var sel = window.getSelection();
    if (i >= e.endOffset) return true;

    var r = document.createRange();
    r.setStart(sp, i);
    r.setEnd(sp, i);
    i++;
    sel.removeAllRanges();
    sel.addRange(r);
    setTimeout(function() {select(sp, i)}, 20);
    return true;
}

</script>
</head>
<body onload="spell();" >
<div id="sp" spellcheck="true" contenteditable="true">
...
```

This worked for me with Chrome. It's a bit ugly, you see the cursor moving in the editable div, but it does the job.